# Is there a difference between assigning several variables in one line and doing it one by one in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, variable-assignment

I am a complete beginner when it comes to Python and recently I tried to reverse a linked list on Leetcode.
I wrote some code, tested it and got a wrong answer. **Here is my code:**

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur = head
        prev = None
        while cur:
            cur.next = prev
            prev = cur
            cur = cur.next
        return prev
```

Then I looked up some solution on the internet and was pretty much identical, except for the fact that every variable assignment in the `while` loop was written in one line. Here it is with some variables names changed:

```
class Solution:  
    def reverseList(self, head):
        cur = head 
        prev = None
        while cur:
            cur.next, prev, cur = prev, cur, cur.next
        return prev
```

And whet I tried tried it out, it worked perfectly. Despite the fact that it seems to be exactly the same. 
**Is there a substantial difference between assigning several variables in one line and doing it one by one. If not, why the second solution works, while the first one doesn't?**

Answer (score 1):

The first solution would work if you'd use a temporary variable:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur = head
        prev = None
        while cur:
            tmp = cur.next
            cur.next = prev
            prev = cur
            cur = tmp
        return prev
```

That's why the second solution can be thought to be preferable, it avoids the extra variable. It's most notable when just swapping the values of two variables, which does require a temporary variable in many languages:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

but not in Python:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Comment: Ohhh. Thanks a lot. I get it now